# PHP files migrated to GoDaddy Windows Hosting, internal links stopped working

Tags: php, url-rewrite-module, windows-hosting

I had my website, written in PHP, on Windows 2003 server. Recently I moved them to GoDaddy's Windows Hosting account. The previous developer had written URL-Rewrite rules in .htaccess which is not working on the new server. All the links on the site show GoDaddy's 404 page.

Here is the content on existing htaccess file:

```
   # Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file
   # Version 3.1.0.64
   # AddHandler x-httpd-php5-3 .php
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (on)? 
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC] 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+) 
   RewriteRule .? http(?%1s)://%2%3 [R=301] 


   # RewriteRule ^(.*?\.asp)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.+)? $1$4?$2=$3 [NC,LP,QSA]

   # RewriteRule ^(.*?\.asp)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.+)? $1$4?$2=$3 [NC,LP,QSA]
   # RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.+)? $2.asp$5?$3=$4 [NC,LP,QSA]
   RewriteRule ^(?!.*(?:admin|blog|images|tinymce|dablog)/)(.*?)/(.*?)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.+)?       $2.php$7?mmid=$3&cmid=$4 [NC,LP,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say that this is most likely you not setting up your httpd.conf file to allow rewrite engine through your Apache server.
To change this, find the line that says

```
LoadModule #rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And Remove the the comment by deleting the #

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

This may not be the entire problem there are numerous more possibilities for this, hopefully this is it.  If not you may want to try to add a custom error file or enable debugging then contact GoDaddy if none of these work.

Comment: Yup, modifying the GoDaddy httpd.conf is totally possible. Not.

Comment: If you can't change your httpd.conf you will want to contact the GoDaddy or look at their FAQ.

Comment: I do not have access to httpd.conf file and its a Windows hosting account. Let me know if there is any other possibility other than rewriting the rules again.

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy do not support ISAPI_Rewrite. Also, you should check what is the Windows server, if it's 2008 or 2012 then you should create a new URL rewriting rules using URL rewrite module - http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module. This means that you should recreate your rewriting rules.

Comment: You are right. GoDaddy does not support ISAPI_Rewrite. I called them on the phone and they said you need to have a VPS for this. They asked me to rewrite the rules in web.config (as its a windows hosting) but I don't know how to write those rules. Any help on this?